# How to use the value of a variable as the name of an array in R

Tags: mysql, arrays, r, stat

i am starting my Rscript with `commandArgs(TRUE` and `variable <- args[1]`.

in `variable` is the name of a column of my mysql database. i select the column dynamically and query with `rohDaten <- dbGetQuery(con, sql)`

the result is an array. i want to do this:

`rohDaten$XXX[rohDaten$XXX==NULL]<-NA` where XXX is the value of `variable`

how can is set XXX to value of variable? i tried many things like variations of `rohDaten$get(variable)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling

```
rohDaten$XXX
```

try

```
rohDaten[variable]
```

This will translate to whatever your variable is, e.g.

```
rohDaten["columnname"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 selected_col <- which(colnames(rohDaten) == variable)
 rohDaten[,selected_col][rohDaten[, selected_col] == NULL] <- NA
```

Comment: I agree with @NickKennedy that the element of a vector cannot be `NULL` and that , therefore, the comparison doesn't make much sense. The entry could be, e.g., a character named `"NULL"` or anything else, but `NULL` means that the element simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of subsetting a `data.frame`. The `$` operator gets or sets a column as its underlying type but can only be used with literal column names, not column names in a variable. The `[[` operator does the same as `$` but takes a character vector (of length 1) as its argument. So these are all equivalent:

```
my_data$potatoes
my_data[["potatoes"]]
variable <- potatoes; my_data[[potatoes]]
```

The `[` operator behaves differently depending on whether there are 1 or 2 arguments. With a single argument, it gets or sets a **`data.frame`** with the requested columns. This is important for repeated subsetting as you're doing:

```
my_data["potatoes"][my_data$id == 4]
```

This will select the column of my_data as a `data.frame` and then try to select columns from it again using a logical vector. This will fail unless there is only one row in my_data, and even then it won't be the desired result.

With 2 arguments, you can select rows, columns or both. Unless `drop=FALSE` is provided, the result will be a vector if only one column is requested.

```
my_data[my_data$id == 4, "potatoes"]
# only elements of my_data$potatoes where my_data$id is 4
my_data[, "potatoes"]
# entirely equivalent to `my_data$potatoes` or `my_data[["potatoes"]]`
```

For your original question, the neatest way of doing this is:

```
rohDaten[rohDaten[, variable]==NULL, variable] <- NA
```

However, this in itself raises another problem. An element of a vector cannot be `NULL`, and testing null would be done with `is.null` anyway. Can you add to your question the output of `dput(rohDaten[, variable])`?

Comment: the idea of setting NULL to NA and then omit it came out of an tutorial and i found it as a candy solution to erase NA an other values i don't wont... isn't it?

'
dput(rohDaten[, variable])
c(1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L,' etc.... 8000 Items

Comment: @Gorn what do items that are `NULL` look like?

Comment: i never looked how they look like. i just thought that after a query it would possible to have NULL in a vector and i wanted to delete this casewise. 

i analyse the results of survey and sometimes there is no input in an important answer (or wrong values) so i omit them.

Comment: If there is no input there will still be something in the table. A blank space, a `NA`, `-99`, or anything else that is unusual. In order to account for these missing values, you should check what is stored in your dataframe in those cases.

Comment: ok, it seems that it imports an NA instead of NULL

THX everything works fine.